# Python read a file opened by another process results in UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, file, encoding

I am trying the contents of a file that is opened in an editor (VIM).

Id est:

```
fileh = open( path, 'r' )
content = fileh.read()
fileh.close()
```

When the file is opened in VIM this results in an error. 
I could understand this if VIM holds an exclusive lock on the file, but this does not seem to be the case, based on the error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It seems to me that VIM writes a non-ascii character in the opened file!

Opening the file using `open( path, 'r', encoding='utf-8')` or utf-16, does not seem to do the trick (utf-8/utf-16 decode errors occur).

Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE: This problem does NOT occur when I open the file in Gedit instead of VIM. Ofcourse this is not a fix, so I still need to find out what goes wrong.

Comment: Could it be possible that VIM has the file opened with some other encoding than UTF-8 or ASCII, for example ISO-8859-1?

Comment: Try opening the file in binary mode.

Comment: @Skurmedel I shall take a look at that.

Comment: @MarkRansom I need to process the text in the files, so opening in binary mode will be problematic.

Comment: @A.J.Rouvoet: It won't be problematic, you just need to `decode` the byte sequence (`str` type) into a string (`unicode` type). You'll find Ned Batchelder's unicode presentation **very** helpful. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: @A.J.Rouvoet, if you open the file in binary mode you'll at least be able to get more information about the problem. Right now you're kind of shooting blind.

Comment: @Daenyth I got that. But isn't that more or less equivalent to the above shown code with the encoding optional parameter of the open method set to `utf-8`? Which also resulted in (a different) `UnicodeDecodeError`

Comment: Is the file actually utf8? You need to know what encoding it really is. Look at at hex dump of it.

Comment: Not before it is opened in VIM... because then I can read it just fine. It would be somewhat odd if opening it in an editor would alter the encoding, right? @Daenyth

Comment: Obligatory: http://bit.ly/unipain

Comment: Oke, this is getting interesting. The problem only occurs if VIM creates a .<filename>.swp file (default). With the :set noswapfile, the problems vanishes. @Daenyth

Comment: @MarkRansom Something else: I looked at the file in binary mode, with the swapfile option, VIM obviously does something with the file.

**While elsewhere opened in VIM, binary content:**
b'b0VIM 7.3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\xb7\xbe\xb2O4\xa9\n\x009\t\x00\x00arjen\x00\x00\x00\x00 ... etc (suprising lot of \x00).

**While exclusively read by python, binary content:**
b'<html>\n\t<head>\n\t</head>\n\t<body>\n\t</body>\n</html>\n'

Answer (score 0):

Oke, I figured it out.

The problem is not with python not being able to decode the files I am interested in, but python reading .swp files, generated by VIM. My program was not filtering the input directory correctly.

Thanks for the help though!